# Help with log differentiation

Tags: calculus, logarithms, implicit-differentiation

The question is if $y = n^t$ then find $\frac{d(\ln(y))}{dt}$

I keep getting $\frac{n}{t}$ as the answer while according to the book its $\ln(n)$

Comment: Try to remember the Logarithmic identities.

Comment: Can you show us the steps you took in order to get to $\frac{n}{t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y = n^t$, then $\ln(y) = \ln(n^t) = t\cdot\ln(n)$. Then when we differentiate with respect to $t$, we treat $n$ as a constant (so $\ln(n)$ is a constant too!), and we get $\ln(n)$.

Comment: d(lny)/dt = d(lny)/dy * dy/dt = 1/y * tn^t-1 can u tell me where im going wrong

Comment: You differentiated $y = n^t$ with respect to $n$ rather than $t$ - a fairly common mistake! Actually, $dy/dt = n^t \cdot \ln (n)$. So then $d(\ln y)/dy \cdot dy/dt = 1/y \cdot (n^t \cdot \ln (n)) = \ln (n)$.

Comment: Oh nevermind i just noticed that i wrote dy/dt while actually  what i was doing was dy/dn

Answer (score 1):

If $y=n^t$, then $\ln y=t\ln n$ and therefore$$\frac{d\ln y}{dt}=\ln n.$$

Comment: Of course you meant $y = n^t$, but the system won't let me edit to change a single character.

Comment: @PapaSmurf I have edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$y = n^t = e^{t \ln(n)}$

So $\ln(y) = t \, \ln(n)$

So ${{d \, \ln(y)} \over dt} = {d \over dt} \ln(n) \, t = \ln(n)$